# Psycopg2 как добавить кириллицу

Tags: python, postgresql, кириллица, psycopg2

Имеется таблица *table* c русскими буквами в строках и такой код:

```
import psycopg2
...
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table')
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Вывод получается такой:

```
[('name', '\xd0\x80\xd0')]
```

Как вывести русские буквы?

Comment: какой у вас `character set` на стороне PostgreSQL?

Comment: @MaxU, как это узнать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454146/getting-the-encoding-of-a-postgres-database

Comment: @MaxU, UTF8 стоит

Comment: @MaxU, если в *print* дописать .decode('utf-8') тоесть: **print('\xd0\x90\xd0\x91'.decode('utf-8')  )** - то все работает. А как сделать чтобы не пришлось дописывать

Answer (score 0):

```
print([(i[0], i[1].encode('utf-8')) for i in cursor.fetchall()])
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]